# Excel Office.js: how to change the fill color of a chart plot area

Tags: excel, office-js

I can easily [change background color](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/chartfill) of an entire chart like:

```
chart.format.fill.setSolidColor("lightgray");
```

and I can change the gridlines in the plot area.

I want to change the fill color of the plot area.  Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry. There is no Office.JS API to do that yet. We are working on such an API. I'm not allowed to predict when it will be available.